# XCode style search field in NSMenu?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, osx-elcapitan, nssearchfield

I'm trying to replicate the Menus displayed in XCode where you can begin typing and it will display a search field and then filter on the keyword entered. Can anyone point to a resource where it's implemented as an example or some clue as to what one needs to do?

Comment: are you referring to the system-wide search feature in the Help menu..?

Comment: @cacau no, try clicking one of the items in the path bar above the editor. If you type in these, a search field appears and the items are filtered and highlighted accordingly. [Screenshot filtering NSView on "draw"](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNrRB5Sa3KE9cVyArAMkTzcz2AjBkoC2I_vol_8_sqz4F6aJiJo2764E9nQAEwc8A/photo/AF1QipMakuIHNo95ua59-ofp-MpGl4dyDpZXk03DxtR3?key=WTA3bGFpMTdBN3ZxaXBTS0NkMVJTTnJDZk40WUZn)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a View to NSMenuItem . In your case , you can assign a view with NSTextField.

Please refer : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMenuItem/view

Comment: Yeah but you need to read more into that, keyevents are *not* supported in menus. Read it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005166-SW1

Comment: But you can add an NSEvent monitor to capture keyboard events when the textfield get focus

Comment: @SheenVempeny I know I am about 5 years late. But I am trying to do something very similar. I set my menuitem to a view that contains a searchfield. But the thing is, at times I can type in it. But at times I cannot. Also, the cursor doesn't appear in the searchfield.